# Cannot recover Linux VM disk in Azure

Tags: ubuntu, azure

The thing is that I have managed to recover one of Ubuntu server disks which caused "Error 'grub_calloc not found' and VM in rescue mode". Also I have swapped this disk with the original VM, but I get notification when I am trying to connect via Serial Console in Azure. When I press enter in Serial Console, nothing happens.

This is the notification I am getting. I have tried to Google, but I, personally, cannot find any related stuff to Linux VMs in Azure.

[Ubuntu Server VM - Serial Console - Azure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2dp1J.png)

This is the picture from boot diagnostics.

[Boot diagnostics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4c4FL.png)

Would really appreciate any answer as Microsoft is sort of failing to help.

Comment: This may sound stupid, but connecting to the serial console may take some time. Have you waited long enough?

Comment: I also suggest to enable `Boot diagnostics`, have a look here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/troubleshooting/boot-diagnostics#enable-boot-diagnostics-on-existing-virtual-machine

Comment: Not stupid at all @Matze :) I have tried to wait, yes. Boot diagnostics seems enabled for the customer. I have attached picture from boot diagnostics. Well, it should not be a problem as we could run this disk on another VM. Seems that this could be related to disk misconfiguration?

Comment: Okay, maybe this will help: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1263125/how-to-fix-a-grub-boot-error-symbol-grub-calloc-not-found. This might help as well: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/72418/problem-with-starting-on-of-my-azure-ubuntu-1804-s.html

Comment: @Matze Thank you for this. I will try the solution.

Answer (score 3):

It should be sufficient to reinstall grub2. Try to follow this steps, that I have borrowed from [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/72418/problem-with-starting-on-of-my-azure-ubuntu-1804-s.html).

1. Create a rescue VM using the [Azure repair VM feature](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/troubleshooting/repair-linux-vm-using-azure-virtual-machine-repair-commands#repair-process-overview)
2. Login to the rescue VM and mount the root disk. Then [chroot(1)](https://linux.die.net/man/1/chroot) to it and reinstall grub.

   $ sudo su –
   $ mkdir /rescue
   $ mount /dev/sdc1 /rescue
   $ for fs in {proc,sys,tmp,dev}; do mount -o bind /$fs /rescue/$fs; done
   $ cd /rescue
   $ chroot /rescue
   $ lsblk <-- this will identify the attached disk, usually /dev/sdc
   $ grub-install /dev/sdc
   $ exit
   $ cd /
   $ for fs in {proc,sys,tmp,dev}; do umount /rescue/$fs; done
   $ umount /rescue
3. Restore the VM by using `az vm repair restore -g MyResourceGroup -n MyVM --verbose`

Further information:

[Chroot environment in a Linux Rescue VM](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/troubleshooting/chroot-environment-linux)

[Enable boot diagnostics on existing virtual machine](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/troubleshooting/boot-diagnostics#enable-boot-diagnostics-on-existing-virtual-machine)

Comment: Thanks @Matze. I got an answer from Microsoft and someone from Linux team is going to contact me soon. I will keep this post updated anyways.

Comment: The thing is that I have managed to recover one of Ubuntu server disks which caused "Error 'grub_calloc not found' and VM in rescue mode". Also I have swapped this disk with the original VM. The thing is that I am trying to run recovered disk on the original VM. I have already swapped the recovered disk. Microsoft already tried to help me, no luck. They told three days ago that someone from their Linux team will contact me, but no answer. :( I am just curious why I cannot run the recovered VM.